# How to check if class has custom __hash__ implemented

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

I need a method to get object's hash which would be consistent across runs.

Currently, I'm using the following approach:

1. Convert object to bytes using `pickle.dumps()`
2. Calculate hash using one of the functions from `hashlib`

This works fine for most objects, but `pickle.dumps` can be quite slow.
For such cases, I can define custom `__hash__` function for the required classes.

Is there a way for me to detect when a class has defined a custom `__hash__` function, so I can use it instead?

Comment: Your approach is not guaranteed to be consistent across runs. `pickle.dumps` may return different pickles for equal objects, or in different runs.

Comment: Try running `pickle.dumps({'a', 'b'})` in a bunch of new Python sessions. You'll see the results aren't consistent from run to run.

Comment: try using the `dir()` function: `print(dir(object))` where object is the object You want to check whether it has that method (obviously You can assign the returned value to a variable and do a simple `if this in there:`)

Comment: @Matiiss: Doesn't work. That gives `True` for almost every possible object, including objects like `object()` that just use `object.__hash__`, and objects like `[]` that aren't hashable at all.

Comment: ok, well then You can do this: `obj.__hash__()` and place it in a `try/except` statement and catch ValueError, otherwise it has that method

Comment: @Matiiss: Doesn't work either. That picks up `object.__hash__`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica ok, I guess I need to go educate myself, otherwise I am talking nonsense that even I don't understand ... it is also late night for me

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica set is not hashable, so that's fine. I only need it to work on objects which are normally hashable, but produce different results between sessions.

Comment: @Rizhiy: Try it with `frozenset({'a', 'b'})`, then. Frozensets are hashable, but you're still not going to get consistent results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this can be checked for with `inspect.ismethoddescriptor`, since the default methods are wrapper descriptors for C methods, so passing the `__hash__` function into it would be `False` if the method was defined on the class

```py
import inspect

class C:
  def __hash__(self):
    pass

class B:
  pass


print(inspect.ismethoddescriptor(C.__hash__))   # -> False
print(inspect.ismethoddescriptor(B.__hash__))   # -> True
print(inspect.ismethoddescriptor(int.__hash__)) # -> True
```

Comment: This reports `False` for classes like `list`, which have `__hash__` set to `None`.

Comment: could also just checking for `None` too work though?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__dict__` attribute of each class. it wouldn't have `__hash__` if it isn't implement in the class itself. works fine with inheritance too.

```
class A:
    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return 'your code here ...'


class B(A):
    pass
```

in this code `B.__dict__.get('__hash__')` returns `None`

Comment: but... tuples do have `__hash__` method but they don't have `__dict__`

Comment: Hmm, good point but I assumed OP only cares about his own classes

Comment: ok, I just reread the question and OP asked for custom `__hash__` attributes meaning that those would most likely come from their own classes, so I guess they won't be checking other objects other than theirs

Comment: If `class Parent` has a custom `__hash__` and `class Child(Parent)` inherits that `__hash__`, this won't detect the inherited method. Given the use case, that's probably not the desired behavior.

Comment: @Matiiss: This is looking for `__hash__` in the *class* `__dict__`, not an instance `__dict__`.

Comment: Also, this considers objects like `object()` and `'asdf'` to have a "custom hash implemented", which probably isn't appropriate behavior for the use case.

Comment: I assumed OP wanted to know if a class has its own implementation without inheritance. because in that case you can just look up for Class.__hash__ and Python goes down through inheritance and finds it

Comment: Sorry, this is not the behaviour I'm looking for. I need it to report `True` for subclasses as well.